# constexpr for sizeof in template does not compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

In Visual C++ 2012 (C++ 11) I am getting error for code

```
template <typename T, T... I>
struct structFoo
{
  static const T sz = sizeof...(I);        (1)
  static constexpr T size = sizeof...(I);  (2)
};
```

the compiler takes the line (1) but complains that the line (2) is an error:
'error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int.

Why?

Comment: Visual Studio 12 doesn't support (or at least has very limited support for) `constexpr`. Visual Studio 15 does.

Comment: The code seems to be correct to me. As usually, it appears to be a bad idea to use anything but C90 or C++98 with Microsoft products. If you want to use anything newer, check their implementation status page to ensure they support the features you need (and then hope for the best).

Comment: @0x499602D2: y u answer in comments??

Answer (score 4):

**Microsoft did not implement support for `constexpr` until Visual Studio 2015.**

You imply that VC++2012 is an implementation of C++11, but that's a gross oversimplification. In fact, various language and library features were added over time across multiple versions; some C++11 features, never mind C++14, are *still* not supported:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#corelanguagetable