# Error: Invalid operands to binary conversion(bitset<8> and int)

Tags: c++

How to iterate through a binary number in c++?

In the mentioned function I'm getting

> invalid operands to binary conversion (bitset<8> and int)

This is the function in my code, which is getting the stated error

```
int value(int x)
{
    int temp=0,counter=0;
    bitset<8> i(x);
    while (i != 0) {
       temp = i % 10;
       if(temp == 1) {
           counter++;
       }
       i = i/10;
  }
  return counter;
}
```

Comment: X is the number whose binary value i need, and then from that binary number I'm supposed to find the number of one's that number has.

Comment: You're not using the bitset here really. Your code is attempting to iterate over the number in decimal not binary.

Comment: If you want to count bits, you have [`bitset::count()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/count).

Comment: i want to count the number of one's in that binary number. so i thought of using that method.

Comment: Look at [how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)

Comment: @WhozCraig . okay but can you please tell me how do i specially calculate the number of 1's in the binary number

Comment: @WhozCraig that needs c++11 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632491/constexpr-for-sizeof-in-template-does-not-compile

Comment: @iksemyonov: `sizeof...` != `sizeof`.

Comment: @Jarod42 sorry, indeed, didn't notice. But isn't the usual `sizeof` `constexpr` as well? I mean, how does it work in templates then.

Comment: @WhozCraig: `sizeof(x)` gives the number of chars in x, not the number of bits.

Comment: @Dani let me uptick that for you, twice if I could =P (no coffee this morning). Post the correct answer and I'll uptick that 4u too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To count the number of 1's in the first 8 bits of x:

```
int value(int x)
{
  return bitset<8>(x).count();
}
```

To count all the bits:

```
int value(int x)
{
  return bitset<sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT>(x).count();
}
```

If you have to use a loop solution: (Adaption to your solution with available functions)

```
int value(int x)
{
    int counter=0;
    bitset<8> i(x);
    while (i != 0) {
       if(i[0] == 1) {
           counter++;
       }
       i >>= 1;
  }
  return counter;
}
```

Comment: @Jarod42: As long as the conversion doesn't overflow there is nothing implementation specific. You are correct, it is better, but in answers I prefer to stick with the OP's signatures.

Comment: hey @Dani , i implemented your code in my program, the only problem is for all the numbers with one 1's in their binary numbers such as 2, 8 I'm getting answer with junk values such as 14343434.

Comment: @SanjayJain: I tested all variants and they all worked. Can you show your whole code?

Comment: yep @dani here it is . #include <iostream>
#include<bitset>
using namespace std;
int value(int i);
int main() {
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t!=0)
{int n=0;
cin>>n;
int i=-1;
int arr[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>arr[i];

}

Comment: for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    for(int x=0;x<n;x++)
    {
        if (value(arr[x+1]) > value(arr[x]))
        { int temp;
               temp = arr[x];             // swap elements
                    arr[x] = arr[x+1];
                    arr[x+1] = temp;
        }
        else if (value(arr[x+1])==value(arr[x]))
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
cout<<arr[0]<<"\n";
cout<<arr[1]<<"\n";
cout<<arr[2]<<"\n";
cout<<arr[3]<<"\n";

t--;
}

}

Comment: int value(int x)
{
    int counter=0;
    bitset<8> i(x);
    while (i != 0) {
       if(i[0] == 1) {
           counter++;
       }
       i >>= 1;
  }
  return counter;
}

Comment: @SanjayJain: 1. This is hard to read, a pastebin would be better. 2. You need to isolate your points of failure, did you try checking what input `value` is getting via a debugger/print? 3. In a quick look I can spot a bug: in the sort(?) loop when `x = n-1`, `arr[x+1]` is out of range.

Comment: the out of range correction worked for me thanks a lot